# Can I use a conditional logit for fixed effects (Chamberlain, 1980) if my assumptions are that the errors are normally distributed?

Tags: probit, clogit

Consider that we have a dichotomous variable $D_{i,t}$ that takes the value of 1 if $Y_{i,t}\geq 0$ and 0 otherwise. And $Y_{i,t}$ is a latent variable defined by:

$Y_{i,t} = \eta_{i} + \sum\limits_{k\in K} \omega_{k,i,t}x_{k,t}$

Where:

$\omega_{k,i,t} \sim N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$

Now I'm facing two problems that call for different approaches:

1. I am conjecturing that the weights $\omega_{k,i,t}$ are normally distributed, so we could estimate $\mu_k$ using a probit regression.
2. Since I have a limited sample for each $i$, I would like to use Chamberlain (1980) approach to differentiate the fixed effects.

I know that the simplest version of the logit and probit are comparable, but I am unsure of how to merge these two conflicting approaches.

Comment: Is $\omega_{k,i,t} \sim N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$ your prior for the weights $\omega_{k,i,t}$?